# Is there an Isomorphism from an abelian Free Group to the additive Group of reals?

Tags: group-theory

When constructing a Free Group $F(S)$ from a set $S$ with only one element, then the resulting Free Group is isomorphic to the additive group of integers.

Now I wonder whether there is an Isomorphism from some abelian Free Group $F(S_R)$ (without further building any Quotient Group from it) to the additive Group of reals and if so, then what would be the Set $S_R$ from which such an abelian Free Group is created?

Thanks for all answers.

Comment: The question is odd: "to construct the additive group of reals as a free group" would mean the reals **is** a free (abelian) group...but it isn't.

Comment: Okay, how should I rephrase it? Or do you mean that there is also no Isomorphism from any abelian Free Group to the additive Group of reals and if so why not?

Comment: I'm not sure what you had in mind to begin with, so to "rephrase it" is something I can't understand: what is **it**  there? Now, *of course* there is a homomorphism from some free abelian group onto $\;\Bbb R\;$ , for example take the free abelian group  $\;A\;$ on a set with cardinality the continuum. The existence of the wanted homomorphism $\;A\to\Bbb R\;$  follows at once from the universal property of free abelian groups.

Comment: @exchange Your question is a little bit confusing. The point is that any free group with more than one generator is not commutative (the free group generated by one element is the integers, but that is more an exception than a rule). So, unless you admit some sort of quotients by relations in the group (such as $xy=yx$, but possibly others) you will never get the additive group of the real numbers.

Comment: @DonAntonio: I know of course that by definition there is a Homomorphism from any Free Group to any other Group. I wanted to know whether one can construct an Isomorphism without building a Quotient Group and suggested myself that the Free Group had to be abelian!

Comment: I edited it and hope that it is not confusing anymore.

Comment: It still is confusing, perhaps because some basics aren't clear to you, yet: build the free *abelian* group $\;F(\Bbb R)\;$ on **the set** $\;\Bbb R\;$ (and I really don't know what you mean by "without further building any quotient group from it"...) and then you get a homomorphism from it to the additive group of reals. Of course, the group $\;F(\Bbb R)\;$ is **not** $\;\Bbb R\;$ since, as commented before, this group is not free abelian, so the homomorphism will be surjective and will have a non-trivial kernel.

Comment: Exactly, it is surjective, and therefore I am asking whether it is possible to build $F(S_R)$ with $S_R\ne \mathbb{R}$ such that the Homomorphism gets an Isomorphism.
And by "without further building any quotient group from it" I mean that if you would generate the normal Subgroup inside $F(\mathbb{R})$ from all sequences that would yield the Identity in $\mathbb{R}$, then $F(\mathbb{R})/N$ would be isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$ but that is not what I want to construct. Rather, by analogy to the case of the additive group of integers, I ask whether there is a set $S_R$ smaller than $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no isomorphism from a free abelian group to the additive group of reals, because the latter is *not* free.

A free abelian group is *reduced*, that is, it has no (nonzero) divisible subgroup. This is easily proved once you realize that a free abelian group $F$ is a direct sum of copies of $\mathbb{Z}$. So, given $x\in F$, $x\ne 0$, you can surely find $n>0$ such that $ny\ne x$, for every $y\in F$.

Since the additive group of $\mathbb{R}$ is clearly divisible, it follows this group is not free.

Comment: It might be worth adding that in some way this is the only reason, since the the reals, being isomporphic to a direct sum of groups isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}$,  are the divisible hull of a free abelian group.

Comment: @quid There are many other reasons for a group not to be free: $\mathbb{Z}[2^{-1}]$ in not free, but has no divisible subgroup either.

Comment: @quid: Could you elaborate on what a divisible hull of a free abelian Group is? Thanks.
And also it is very interesting that the reals are isomorphic to a direct sum of groups isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}$. How to construct that isomorphism?

Comment: And also, if this is true that the reals are a direct sum of groups isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{Q}$ is countable, that is, there is an Isomorphism from $\mathbb{Z}$ to $\mathbb{Q}$, then why is it not possible to construct an Isomorphism from a direct sum of $\mathbb{Z}$ to $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: @exchange For every abelian group $G$ there exists a unique (up to isomorphism) embedding of $G$ into a divisible group $D$ such that, for every $x\in D$, there is $n>0$ with $nx\in G$; in this case $D$ is the *divisible hull* of $G$. For a free abelian group $\mathbb{Z}^{(X)}$, the divisible hull is $\mathbb{Q}^{(X)}$. Note that $\mathbb{Q}$ being countable doesn't mean it is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: @egreg: Okay, thanks, very helpful. 
Still, if the reals are "isomporphic to a direct sum of groups isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}$" as quid said, I do not see, what forbids me to construct an Isomorphism from a direct sum of $\mathbb{Z}$ to the direct sum of $\mathbb{Q}$ that are then isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: @exchange There is ***no*** isomorphism from a free group to $\mathbb{Q}$ to begin with, because $\mathbb{Q}$ is divisible and a free group isn't.

Comment: @exchange in addition to what is already said note that the direct sum is an infinite (indeed uncountable) direct sum, the $X$ in egreg's comment is uncountable. Note that in this case still every 'coordinate vector' has only finitely many non-zero entries (as it is a direct sum, not direct product and they differ for inifinite index set).

Comment: I did not say that the only reason for some abelian group not to be free is it being divisible. Rather that the only reason the reals are not an image of a free group is that one cannot divide in a free group, in the sense that if one "adds" division to a free group one gets the iso. . Anyway, the first part was not intended as a precise statement but as a paraphrase of the second part. The main point of my comment was this second part, which I thought might be relevant to OP, given that they seem mostly interested in understanding the additive structure of the reals.

Comment: @quid yes, I understood your meaning of "only" in the above context.
And egreg, I will now mark your answer as solution to my question. Thanks.
PS: Was it really such a bad question?

Comment: @exchange Not really so bad, but it could be phrased in a much better way: “is the additive group of reals a free abelian group”?